# Make/Save a Graph where the Graph starts at point X if it meets a condition

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am extremely new to python (and posting on StackOverflow) and I have created a program that takes in a 2 column data table and converts the y values to either a one or a zero depending on whether it meets a condition. I then have those values searched for the longest consecutive ones. I want to have a plot that shows the graph of the original values at the area of the longest consecutive ones and the data points 20 before and 20 after the area of the longest consecutive ones, any advice?

Sorry if this is maybe vague, I will try my best to answer questions you might have, however, I did add my code to this post.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

voltageslothigh = 0.9
voltageslotlow = 0.1

DefaultData = np.genfromtxt(r'''D:\DrRoberson\1kHz\1kHz_01.csv''', delimiter=',', skip_header=2) #Loads in the CSV file as an array

MinimumValues = np.amin(DefaultData, axis=0)#Find Minimum Values so that they can be added to all of the voltages to have a lowest point of zero
MinimumVoltage = MinimumValues[1]
DefaultVoltages = DefaultData[:,1]
DefaultTimes = DefaultData[:,0]
NewVoltages = np.array(DefaultVoltages) - MinimumVoltage 
MaximumVoltage = np.amax(NewVoltages, axis=0) #Determines the maximum voltage and time value [time irrelevant]

ScaledVoltages = np.array(NewVoltages) / MaximumVoltage #Calculating on a spectrum of 0-1
MaximumScaledVoltage = np.amax(ScaledVoltages)
MinimumScaledVoltage = np.amin(ScaledVoltages)

ScaledVoltages[ScaledVoltages < voltageslotlow] = 0
ScaledVoltages[ScaledVoltages > voltageslothigh] = 0
ScaledVoltages[ScaledVoltages > 0] = 1
ScaledData = np.column_stack((DefaultTimes, ScaledVoltages))

def len_iter(items):
    return sum(1 for _ in items)

def consecutive_one(data):
    return max(len_iter(run) for val, run in groupby(data) if val)

TimeDifference = DefaultTimes[1] - DefaultTimes[0]

RiseTime = TimeDifference * consecutive_one(ScaledVoltages)

print('ConsecutiveOnes:', consecutive_one(ScaledVoltages))

print('RiseTime:', RiseTime)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(200,200))
plt.plot(DefaultTimes, ScaledVoltages)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(1e-300,1e1)
ax.set_xlim(-5,5)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Time, Miliseconds, Rise Time = ')
plt.ylabel('ScaledVoltage')
plt.grid()
fig.savefig('VoltageTime.pdf', dpi = 500)
```